# Como fazer a instalação do SQL Server junto com a aplicação C# criada?

Tags: c#, sql-server, instalador

Tenho um projeto C# e preciso que quando eu criar o seu instalador seja instalado também na máquina do cliente o SQL Server 2008. Seria possível fazer isso?

Comment: Se o cliente for um indivíduo, ao invés dum cliente empresarial, considera usar Compact SQL ou sqlite

Comment: Seu cliente possuí licença de um SQL Server? Eu acho bem complicado instalar um SQL Server. Quando você vende um produto, você acaba vendendo também um serviço de manutenção. Isso significa configurar acesso remoto para suporte etc. Se a idéia é ter uma base de dados na máquina, siga a dica do @dcastro ou use um SQLite algo do tipo, sem precisar de algo muito pesado.

Comment: Na verdade a instalação a ser feita é a do SQL Server Express e esse é um requisito que de fato deve ser cumprido, não podendo usar as opções sugeridas, mas agradeço e consegui resolver com a resposta do Cigano Morrison Mendez. Valeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É possível.

O procedimento é bastante grande pra uma resposta [e pode ser encontrado aqui](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd981032%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). O tutorial explica como embutir na instalação do seu sistema uma instância do SQL Server 2008. Creio que funcione também para o SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Funcionou a instalação, porém por padrão é utilizado na instalação o sistema de autenticação do Windows. Como seria se eu quisesse usar o sistema de autenticação do SQL Server?

Comment: Aí você teria que ver como configurar a autenticação usando modo misto. Não sei como fazer isso, mas deve ter um jeito neste tutorial.